# Grails run-app not reloading changes to other files under conf folder

Tags: grails

I have some additional text files under grails-app/conf that I am reading explicitly with java.io.File.  I am getting the base directory for `conf` using the classpath but then opening the files directly.

Specifically - I have a folder `grails-app/conf/folder` and reading a file like this:

```
new File(new File(this.class.getResource("/folder/").getFile(), "file.txt")
```

`folder/file.txt` is actually read from `~/.grails/2.2.2/projects/myProject/resources/folder`

How do I get `grails run-app` to push these txt files out when changed, similar to `.groovy` files?

Comment: Have you tried [External Config Reload](http://grails.org/plugin/external-config-reload) plugin? You would need `grails.plugins.reloadConfig.files = []` configuration as mentioned in [documentation](https://github.com/adaptivecomputing/grails-external-config-reload#configuration).

Comment: external config would work if they were actually properties files or Groovy classes, but they're just raw text files.